# an/bei etwas sparen

Tags: usage, preposition

When talking about spending less money on something, is there any difference between ***an*** and ***bei*** *etwas sparen*?

For example,

> ***am*** Essen sparen vs. ***beim*** Essen sparen
>   ***am*** Heizen sparen vs. ***beim*** Heizen sparen
>   ***bei*** den Reisekosten sparen vs. ***an*** den Reisekosten sparen

Answer (score 7):

One uses accusative to denote the thing one saves and *bei* for the process (*Autofahren*, *Buchen*, *Duschen*, *usw.*)

> Man spart *Geld/Benzin/Zeit* beim *Einkaufen/Tanken/Fahren*

What *an* concerns, there are fixed constructs as:

> an nichts sparen
>   am Essen sparen
>   am falschen Fleck sparen
>   an allen Ecken sparen

Comment: From your answer I would expect "Ich spare *an* Benzin/Geld/Zeit" are correct sentences, but it should be "Ich spare Benzin/Geld/Zeit".

Comment: @Iris Klingt vernünftig. Jetzt weiß ich nicht mehr. Ich basierte auf dem Duden-Beispiel *bei dem Essen war an nichts gespart worden*. Ich habe das falsch pauschalisiert (?).

Comment: Das "an" in dem  Beispiel gehört mMn zum feststehenden Ausdruck "an nichts sparen" (https://www.openthesaurus.de/synonyme/edit/36202). Ein zweiter Satz mit "an" wäre "sie spart am falschen Ende" (http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/sparen)

Comment: Ansonsten fallen mir keine Sätze mit "sparen" und "an" ein, sondern entweder wird "beim" oder kein Artikel/bestimmter Artikel genutzt.

Comment: Don't you think there is a slight shift in meaning? "Ich _spare Benzin_" (=I'm saving gas.) vs. "Ich _spare **an** Benzin_" (=I'm saving money on gas.)

Comment: Ich würde auf keinen Fall den Eindruck erwecken wollen, *an* trete nur in festen Wendungen auf. Ich würde auch @stillenat zustimmen, nur das der Unterschied nicht klein ist. Wer *am* Gold spart, versagt sich in der Regel etwas, z.B. die Vergoldung. Nicht so wer Gold spart!

Comment: @Ludi Ja. Nicht meine erste Antwort. Ich habe vielleicht Iris' Kommentar verlesen. Ich habe keine Zeit für Edits und werde die in 2 Monaten mehr nicht haben. Bitte selber korrigieren.

Answer (score 4):

There can be a difference but it is easier to see with other examples.
Let’s take hobbies.

> Er spart an seinen Hobbies — He wants to spend less on his hobbies.
>    Er spart bei seinen Hobbies — He saves money during his hobbies (perhaps his hobby is a really cheap one so he spends less during the time he does this than he would normally.)

Mostly c.p. had it right with his/her first sentence.

> One uses accusative to denote the thing one saves and bei for the process

Er spart am Benzin oder er spart beim Autofahren indem er ökonomischer fährt.
He saves on (?) gas or he saves while driving by doing it more economically.

In both cases he pays less money for gas. In the first part he just buys less, in the other he needs ness because he’s more careful how much he uses.

Er spart am Essen oder beim Essen ist — is not as easy to understand as Essen can be both, the food and the process of eating. And this is where the difference is (or at least can be).

Comment: Welcome to German Language Stack Exchange. Feel free to take a [tour] of the site. Visit the [help] for all questions about how it works. Nice first answer =)

Answer (score 1):

I believe, the distinction between the two is the reason, WHY you spend less.

> Beim Essen sparen

would be: You eat less or cheaper.

> Am Essen sparen

would be: The cook chooses less valuable or even bad ingredients. So he can sell it cheaper or make more profit with it.
So "beim" is more "userfriendly". ;)